# Spring Boot RestTemplate.postForObject to Firebase Messaging not returning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to tie Google's Firebase Messaging platform into my app, and I'm trying to use Spring's built in RestTemplate REST abstraction to simplify it.

I'm currently trying to:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());

MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
headers.add("Authorization", "key=" + Constants.FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY);
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

HttpEntity<FireBasePost> entity = new HttpEntity<>(fbp, headers);
URI uri;
uri = new URI(firebaseApi);

FireBaseResponse fbr = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, entity, FireBaseResponse.class);
```

The FireBasePost object just contains the required fields for the POST Message API: [Firebase API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol) - and I have verified the request Entity works by posting with String.class, so the response is unmarshalled JSON.

However, with trying to get the response to marshall directly into the FireBaseResponse object, the call to postForObject hangs and never returns.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FireBaseResponse {

    public Integer multicast_id;
    public Integer success;
    public Integer failure;
    public Integer canonical_ids;

    public FireBaseResponse() {}
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this call never completes.  I would love to be able to have the response directly into an object.

Comment: I believe `FireBaseResponse` property names do not follow right convention. Try with camel case names (`multicastId`, `canonicalIds`, etc:.). Can you please post your Firebase response?

Comment: Are you able to handle these notifications received on client side? For instance, in the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> ())` delegate?

Comment: You can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172021/3073945

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
    package yourpackage;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class FirebaseResponse {

        private long multicast_id;
        private Integer success;
        private Integer failure;
        private Object canonical_ids;

        public FirebaseResponse() {
        }

        //---- use this one ----
        public boolean is_success() {
            if (getSuccess() == 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public long getMulticast_id() {
            return multicast_id;
        }

        public void setMulticast_id(long multicast_id) {
            this.multicast_id = multicast_id;
        }

        public Integer getSuccess() {
            return success;
        }

        public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
            this.success = success;
        }

        public Integer getFailure() {
            return failure;
        }

        public void setFailure(Integer failure) {
            this.failure = failure;
        }

        public Object getCanonical_ids() {
            return canonical_ids;
        }

        public void setCanonical_ids(Object canonical_ids) {
            this.canonical_ids = canonical_ids;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FirebaseResponse{" +
                    "multicast_id=" + multicast_id +
                    ", success=" + success +
                    ", failure=" + failure +
                    ", canonical_ids=" + canonical_ids +
                    '}';
        }
    }

//--------------- USAGE ------------------
                ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
            interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Authorization", "key=" + FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY));
            interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Content-Type", "application/json"));
            restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);


        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
            // JsonArray registration_ids = new JsonArray();
            // body.put("registration_ids", registration_ids);
            body.put("to", "cfW930CZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxipdO-bjHLacHRqQzC0aSXlRFKdMHv_aNBxkRZLNxxxxxxxxxxx59sPW4Rw-5MtwKkZxxxxxxxgXlL-LliJuujPwZpLgLpji_");
            body.put("priority", "high");
            // body.put("dry_run", true);

            JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
            notification.put("body", "body string here");
            notification.put("title", "title string here");
            // notification.put("icon", "myicon");

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("key1", "value1");
            data.put("key2", "value2");

            body.put("notification", notification);
            body.put("data", data);



            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(body.toString());

            FirebaseResponse firebaseResponse = restTemplate.postForObject("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", request, FirebaseResponse.class);
            log.info("response is: " + firebaseResponse.toString());


            return new ResponseEntity<>(firebaseResponse.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);

//--------------- HELPER CLASS ------------------    

    import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
    import org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpRequestWrapper;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class HeaderRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

        private final String headerName;

        private final String headerValue;

        public HeaderRequestInterceptor(String headerName, String headerValue) {
            this.headerName = headerName;
            this.headerValue = headerValue;
        }

        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            HttpRequest wrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(request);
            wrapper.getHeaders().set(headerName, headerValue);
            return execution.execute(wrapper, body);
        }
    }
```