# Firebase cloud messaging rest API spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to make a Rest API in Spring Java for a multi tier arch in which DAO, Controller, Service manager needs to be build for a Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send push notifications messages to android application, but I can not able configure a server in Java to send notifications to devices. 
How could I?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way that you can achieve this:

**Step 1**: 
   Create project on firebase and generate server key.

**Step 2**:
Generate a json object for fcm server. Here message may contains data object and notification object. It must also have receiver fcm id. Sample json is like:

```
{
    "notification":
        {
            "notificationType":"Test",
        "title":"Title ",
        "body":"Here is body"
        },
    "data":
        {"notificationType":"Test",
        "title":"Title ",
        "body":"Here is body"
        },
        "to":"dlDQC5OPTbo:APA91bH8A6VuJ1Wl4TCOD1mKT0kcBr2bDZ-X8qdhpBfQNcXZWlFJuBMrQiKL3MGjdY6RbMNCw0NV1UmbU8eooe975vvRmqrvqJvliU54bsiT3pdvGIHypssf7r-4INt17db4KIqW0pbAkhSaIgl1eYjmzIOQxv2NwwwwXg"
}
```

**Step 3** :
Write a Rest caller service that will communicate with fcm server by following url:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Here is the sample working code:

```
public class PushNotificationServiceImpl {
    private final String FIREBASE_API_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    private final String FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY = "YOUR_SERVER_KEY";


    public void sendPushNotification(List<String> keys, String messageTitle, String message) {


        JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();

        msg.put("title", messageTitle);
        msg.put("body", message);
        msg.put("notificationType", "Test");

        keys.forEach(key -> {
            System.out.println("\nCalling fcm Server >>>>>>>");
            String response = callToFcmServer(msg, key);
            System.out.println("Got response from fcm Server : " + response + "\n\n");
        });

    }

    private String callToFcmServer(JSONObject message, String receiverFcmKey) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "key=" + FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY);
        httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("data", message);
        json.put("notification", message);
        json.put("to", receiverFcmKey);

        System.out.println("Sending :" + json.toString());

        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(json.toString(), httpHeaders);
        return restTemplate.postForObject(FIREBASE_API_URL, httpEntity, String.class);
    }
}
```

You have to just call `sendPushNotification(List<String> receiverKeys, String messageTitle, String message)` then receiver will get push message

Thanks :)

Comment: This works flawlessly. If the `data` AND `notification` required, or can we choose only one of them?

Comment: what is the contents of list<String> receiverkeys?

Comment: Here, receiver key's are receiver's device fcm key. This key will found from clients after absorbing the fcm in client side.

Comment: HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<?????>(json.toString(), httpHeaders);    What is the type of new HttpEntity, when use it it  says Error:(47, 45) java: cannot infer type arguments for org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<>

Answer (score 1):

@Autowire the FCM in your @Component class after configure your FCM account. 
[tutorial](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/firebase-cloud-messaging-server-spring-to-push-notification-example-spring-boot)

Comment: habil sir its not working it is having Interceptor service class which is having various libraries in intercept method like   import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;

Comment: these libraries i am not being able to import .i am not also able to find accurate jar file for these libraries so that i can import

Comment: Check this out : [link](https://github.com/bane73/firebase4j) and don't forget to add spring-boot-starter-web dependency.