# Firebase Cloud Message with Rest API Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build an app which will send notifications to the users according to the data changes from Rest API.

i.e A user subscribes that he wants to be notified when Spain scores the goal against Portugal. So my question is, is it possible to connect that link which sends requests to Rest API which I'm using to retrieve data **to FCM** or should I look for other product which will solve my problem?

Comment: You can just integrate FCM api with your Rest API

Comment: @SafvanCK can you give me a hint where to look for a guide how to do that? I'm looking at official guides at firebase site and I'm kinda lost between so many new terms. Thank you for your answer

Comment: When you say "data changes from Rest API", does it mean change into the Firebase database for example?

Comment: @Kuba can you please more specific on your requirement

Comment: @SafvanCK maybe I will make it with resources which you have provided for me

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I meant that if I can somehow make FCM observe constant changes in Rest API(with providen link which responses with data in JSON format like this: [link](https://andfun-weather.udacity.com/weather)) and then if FOR EXAMPLE temperature reaches 35 degrees - user gets notified while app is not running

Comment: You can view bellow link. It has Spring java implementation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172021/3073945

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with Cloud Functions, which "run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests", see the general doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

You could regularly trigger an HTTPS Cloud Functions that would:

1. Call the REST API, e.g. with Request (https://github.com/request/request)
2. Based on the response of the REST API, send a notification with FCM.

To send a FCM notification via Cloud Function, have a look a this official Firebase sample https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

To call your HTTPS Cloud Function regurlarly, you have to trigger it via http through a cron-job.

Have a look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events and
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA. You could also use another online CRON service to call the HTTPS Function, like https://www.easycron.com/

Note that you would need to be on Blaze Plan to be able to query an outside service.

Comment: I will take a look into these resources, thank you for your answer Sir!

Comment: @Kuba Hello. Did you have the opportunity to give a try to the solution I proposed?

Comment: Hello, unfortunantlly I gave up on this topic because if I remember corectly, to use these kind of services require paid plan and I wanted to use this in my educational project and didn't want to spend any money on it. To be honest it I felt like it was kind of too advanced for me to implement this in my app that's why i moved on. Anyway, I really appreacaite your time Sir, next time when I will need this kind of feature maybe I will give it a try :) Thank you.